# How can I restore Spotlight to menu bar?

Tags: macos, spotlight, menu-bar

I removed the Spotlight icon from the menu bar. I would like to restore it.

I tried the recommended method:

```
sudo mdutil -a -i on
sudo chmod 755 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search
sudo killall SystemUIServer
```

…which did not help. The command keys still work, but I would like to see the icon. I read the suggestion to reinstall the system and would prefer not to do that.

Does anyone have a different suggestion?

Problem solved: The article from OSXDaily worked perfectly. Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: How did you remove it?

Comment: Did you do a system restart after running the commands above?

Comment: As mentioned in this article on osxdaily [see below], the user hid it by using `sudo chmod 600 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search` followed by `killall SystemUIServer`  
Link to article:http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/12/hide-spotlight-menu-icon-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 2):

Just to make an official answer.

User [M K](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/31743/m-k) referenced an [article in osXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/12/hide-spotlight-menu-icon-mac-os-x/) that explains how to both hide and un-hide the **Spotlight** icon.

> #### Show the Spotlight Menu Again
>
> Getting the Spotlight icon back is a matter of bringing the permissions back to their default setting in OS
>   X. Go back to the Terminal app by relaunching it from
>   /Applications/Utilities/, and then enter the exact command syntax
>   below: `sudo chmod 755
>   /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search`
>
> Hit the return key, then follow this up with killing the
>   SystemUIServer process again: `killall SystemUIServer` The system menu
>   bar will refresh, and the Spotlight menu will be visible again.

I just tested this on **OS X Yosemite 10.10.5** with success.